# I have problem with socket.io , how can i show data on html page when refresh page (ctrl f5 or ctrl or ctrl r etc )

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I can show data on page when I emit the socket with nodejs ,But if I don't emit and I refresh the html page data does not show on the html page .

**nodejs  server**

```java
global.io = socket(server);
```

**nodejs  controller**

```java
    module.exports.Onlineusers = function (req, res) {
        io.emit('Onlineusers', { total: req.body.total });
        res.status(200).json({ msg: true });
    };
```

**html**

```java
    var socket2 = io.connect('<?= SOCKET_ADDRESS2; ?>');
    
    socket2.on("Onlineusers", (data) => {
        $('#live_onlineusers').html(data.total);
    });
```

If I use nodejs controller I can see data on html page ,But if I refresh page I can not see data on html page. I want to see on the data socket in html page when i refresh page

Comment: you request it, or emit on connect#

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the data in a sql lite database or in local-storage of the browerser so on refresh load the existing data